# Torsion in abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are finite abelian groups that obey the following exact sequence
$$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow1$$ and $$A[m]:=\{a\in A:a^m=1\}$$ is the following inequality true or false, why?
$$|B[m]|\leq |A[m]||C[m]|$$

I know that it is false when I take away the finite condition. If it is false, is there some other nice upper bound on $|B[m]|$?

One way to start is by restricting attention to $p$ primary invariant, but I am not sure how to proceed. Maybe taking the quotient of $A[p]$ and $f(A[p])$ will help where $f:A\rightarrow B$ is the homomorphism in the exact sequence, and then induction, but I am not sure if the details follow.

Comment: Do you want $1\to A\to B\to C\to1$.  If it's _split_, the result is true, because $B=A\oplus C$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster, I do not want that

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that $A,B,C$ "obey the given exact sequence". Instead, you assume that there exists such an exact sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functor $F(M) = M\otimes \mathbb{Z}_m = M/mM$ is right-exact. Furthermore, if $M$ is finite, then $\#mM = \#(M/M[m])$ and $\#M[m] = \#F(M)$. The exact sequence
\begin{align*}
F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C) \to 1
\end{align*}
then implies 
\begin{align*}
\#F(C) = \frac{\# F(B)}{\# \ker F(B) \to F(C)} = \frac{\#F(B)}{\# \operatorname{im} F(A) \to \#F(B)} \geq \frac{\#F(B)}{\#F(A)};
\end{align*}
that is, $\#F(B) \leq \#F(A) \#F(C)$.

Comment: The assumption of finiteness is not necessary for $\#mM = \#(M/M[m])$ but rather is necessary to be able to deduce $\#M[m] = \#F(M)$ from that.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Of course, though you have to either ensure that $mM = M/M[m]$ is finite or be more careful about cardinalities. (The important part, though, is that it's the latter equality that really uses the fact that $M$ is finite nontrivially.)

Comment: @anomaly can you justify or cite why the functor F(M) is right exact?

Comment: @User164144: That tensoring with a fixed module is right-exact? It's a standard result; the stacks project, for example, has a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the exact contravariant functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ to your exact sequence yields an exact sequence $$1\to C\to B\to A$$ since $\operatorname{Hom}(X,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\cong X$ for any finite abelian group $X$.  But now the conclusion is trivial, since the maps in this exact sequence restrict to a short exact sequence $$1\to C[m]\to B[m]\to D\to 1$$ where $D$ is the image of $B[m]$ under the map $B\to A$ and in particular is a subgroup of $A[m]$, so $|B[m]|=|C[m]||D|\leq|C[m]||A[m]|$.